# tSQL - SQL 2008 - Nested query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, nested

I'm trying to get the maximum datetime per date, per item, per variant from a list of transactions.

My attempt so far is:

```
SELECT  variantid, 
        itemid, 
        MAX(STARTDATE) as MaximumDateTimeForThisDay 
FROM myTable 
GROUP BY    variantid,
            itemid, 
            DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, t1.MODIFIEDDATETIME), 0) --- to remove the time stamp
```

I need to get the latest price PER DAY for each item and variant since the price can change throughout the day but I always want the latest price for that day per item.

Ultimately, I'd like this have my output be the most recent price per item per variant per day. I'm sure that can be done in one (nested) query as well but can't figure it out.

Please help if you can!

Comment: ** The above query still gives me more than one result per day. Thanks again

Comment: Could you give some sample data and a desired result? "maximum datetime per date, per item, per variant" isn't clear to me.

Comment: Could you give some example data and the expected result?

Comment: I tried posting sample data but it isn't formatted very well. Can I post screenshots or images?

Comment: Basically if I have two records for item 123, variant abc and one record has timestamp 3/6/14 at 3pm with a amount of $10 and I have a second record with timestamp 3/6/14 at 4pm with cost of $11, I want only one record (with the latest timestamp) with the most recent cost whether it is less or more. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

The code you have above to remove the time component from the modification date is not working. Rather than jumping through your `DATEADD` hoops to remove the time, just convert the column to a `date`.

```
SELECT variantid, itemid, MAX(STARTDATE) as MaximumDateTimeForThisDay
FROM myTable GROUP BY variantid, itemid, convert(date, t1.MODIFIEDDATETIME)
```

Comment: This still gives me duplicate entries per day. Here is some sample data:   <BR>    VARIANTID STARTDATE PriceGroup AMOUNT ITEMID newStartDate<BR>
7456 Sunday, July 14, 2013 4:21:46 PM Online 50 CUVACR omit record<BR>
7456 Sunday, July 14, 2013 4:19:15 PM Online 75 CUVACR 7/14/2014<BR>
7456 Sunday, July 14, 2013 4:21:46 PM Full Price 50 CUVACR omit record<BR>
7456 Sunday, July 14, 2013 4:19:15 PM Full Price 75 CUVACR 7/14/2014<BR>
7456 Sunday, July 14, 2013 4:21:46 PM Outlet 50 CUVACR omit record<BR>
7456 Sunday, July 14, 2013 4:19:15 PM Outlet 75 CUVACR 7/14/2014<BR>

Comment: Grouping this way cannot give you duplicate entries for the same variantid and itemid within a given day. If you want to update your question with actual SQL (unless this is truly the statement and tables you're using) and table data, I can try to help further. Comments don't allow much formatting, so please edit your question instead.

Comment: Okay, I tried again and must have made a mistake earlier. But I need one entry for the most recent date with the related amount.
If I use this:
 SELECT   max(MODIFIEDDATETIME) AS STARTDATE, AMOUNT, ITEMID  FROM my table 
 WHERE   itemID = 'V9800' 
 group by convert(date, MODIFIEDDATETIME),  amount

I get two rows since there are two different amounts. 

If I use this:

 SELECT   max(MODIFIEDDATETIME) AS STARTDATE, ITEMID
 FROM my table
 WHERE   itemID = 'V9800' 
 group by convert(date, MODIFIEDDATETIME)

I get 1 row but I don't have amount. Do I need a nested query?

Comment: ill put queries above. I can't figure out how to edit